# RequestVerificationToken sent but not recognized

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc 5 application and I'm trying to modernize it by implementing ajax calls sending json objects.

When executing calls with [AntiForgeryToken] tag on my form I get this message: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Request Headers:
[image]

Raw:
[image]

JSON:
[image]

Code to execute the call:

```
addRequestVerificationToken: function (data) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    return data;
},

var j = fileUploader.addRequestVerificationToken({ user: formData });

fileUploader.post("/AccountManager/Create/", JSON.stringify(j), function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    if (data.result === 'success') {
        window.location.replace("/AccountManager/");
    }
});

$.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                headers: fileUploader.addRequestVerificationToken({})
              })
```

Controller signature:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateUserViewModel user)
        {
}
```